# Why is the triple phase diagram of water different from the general substances?

Tags: equilibrium

The fusion curve of triple phase diagram of water and fusion curve of triple phase diagram of  general substances is different. Why is it so?

[image: Following are the fusion curves of water and general substance (actually my teacher gave me this diagram)]

Comment: Different? To me, they look pretty much the same.

Comment: No, they don't. Please look at the images that I have sent (the diagrams were given to me by my teacher).

Comment: Your diagrams are exaggerated a great deal. In fact, the curve in both cases is very nearly vertical. The different slope, though, is indeed a fact that requires an explanation. It has to do with the volume change.

Comment: There is no such thing as "general substance". There might be typical behaviour and unusual behaviour but "general substance" is bad terminology and a ridiculous overgeneralisation.

Answer (score 0):

The phase diagram of water is peculiar for the *negative* slope of the line separating the solid, and the liquid for the representation of pressure in function of temperature:

[image]

(slightly modified, [credit](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/13%3A_States_of_Matter/13.20%3A_Phase_Diagram_for_Water)).

As indicated in the comment by `@Ivan Neretin`, this is due to volume change.  You may recall that $\pu{3.98 ^\circ{}C}$ is special for water because at any temperature above *as well as below* the density of water is less that at this extreme.  Thus the volume expansion of ice cracks rocks; and while ice skating (i.e., putting you body weight on a pointy small surface area, thus increasing the pressure), you may generate a thin film of molten water.  This applies for the transition between liquid water and hexagonal ice formed under about ambient pressure. (There are multiple other [polymorphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(materials_science)) of solid water ([an entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice)) in addition to the one frequently seen.)

Much more frequently experienced is a positive slope for the solid-liquid phase boundary, e.g., for $\ce{CO2}$:

[image]

(from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550010/is-there-any-relevance-between-phase-diagram-and-energy)).